# sqlalchemy sum with join more than one table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have customers , payments , orders,

how to query customer.name , customer.total_payments , customer.total_orders .
I tried using subqueries it works fine .
but is there way to achieve with join instead of subqueries

```
query = (
        db.query(
            Customer,
            total_orders,
        )
        .select_from(Customer)
        .outerjoin(Customer.orders)
        .group_by(Customer)
    )
```

passed total_orders

```
 query = (
        db.query(
            Customer,
            total_payments,
      
        )
        .select_from(Customer)
        .outerjoin(Customer.payments)
        .group_by(Customer)
    )
```

passed total_payments

```
query = (
    db.query(
        Customer,
        total_orders ,
        total_payments ,
    )
    .select_from(Customer)
    .outerjoin(customer.payments)
    .outerjoin(customer.orders)
    .group_by(Customer)
    
)
```

failed